# I need help to print a dictionary of objects as a html table

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, flask, wtforms

My flask app is collecting data using flask-wtf forms perfectly. After collecting

```
@home.route('/add-new', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def newlist():
    return redirect( url_for('auth.login'))

    form = ShoppingList()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #insert to list
        item_id = len( shopping_lists ) + 1        
        shopping_list = ShoppingCart(session["email"], form.title.data, form.price.data, 
                                        form.quantity.data, item_id, form.description.data)
        addToDic(session["email"], shopping_list)
        result = shopping_lists
        flash("List saved okay")
        return render_template('home/dashboard.html', title="Dashboard", result = result)

    #Render the dashboard template on the /dashboard route    
    return render_template('home/newlist.html',form=form, title="Add new")
```

My question is how do I print the result dic to a table in flask template. Here is the template code

```
<h3>HOME</h3>
                  <p>{{ utils.flashed_messages() }}</p>                   
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Item name</th>
                            <th>price</th>
                            <th>quantity</th>
                            <th>description</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>

                          </tr>                          
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Thanks alot. Please reachout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consult `jinja2` [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/) as it is really well-written and comprehensive source of knowledge and what you want to do is pretty straightforward task which is explained early on in there.

Here is a working example:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

@app.route('/')
def index():
    my_objects = [
        MyObj('I am a super-cool object!', 1000, 1),
        MyObj('I am a cooler object!', 2000, 2),
        MyObj('I am the coolest object!', 3000, 3),
    ]
    return render_template('index.html', my_objects=my_objects)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <th>Item name</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for ob in my_objects %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ob.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ ob.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ ob.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result webpage:**
[image]